# Undefined method `title=' for #<Post id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`BoardController` code:

[image: BoardController]

Error message:

[image: NoMethodError]

Comment: Seems your post model is not having `title`  attribute.

Comment: Sov, please edit your question and include your code an error as text (with code formatting) instead of using images. Also provide more information related to the error, i.g. `Post` model and the migration file or definition of `posts` table in your *schema.rb* file.

Answer (score 0):

here is the correction for your post controller

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:perusahaan).permit(:title,:content)
  end
```

you should put post_params with new

and if you don't have post_params, you can create on bottom of your controller see sample code above

Comment: Although this code is a better practice for the controller, it is not the solution to the problem, and it will result in the same output (i.e. an error). The problem is that `Post` model doesn't have a `title` attribute (or is not accessible), hence the `Undefined method 'title'` error.